# How do I use Haddock with c2hs?

Tags: haskell, haddock, c2hs

I am using c2hs to write some haskell
bindings, and I would like to use Haddock
to document automatically generated constructors and function parameters. However,
c2hs ignores the comments;

```
{#enum define WinPos
  {
   CA as HA -- ^ This comment is not shown in the .hs file
  ,CB as HB -- ^ Neither this one
  } 
  deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)#}
```

How can I get Haddock documentation for these fields without
writing too much FFI code?

Comment: I guess this is relevant: https://github.com/haskell/c2hs/issues/62

Comment: I'm the maintainer of C2HS.  That issue is on my list and should get fixed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now supported in the latest version of c2hs.